# Transitioning VBA Code to ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, vba

I am moving some applications written in VBA that have been working in ArcGIS 10.1 to ArcGIS 10.2.2.  I have the ArcGIS VBA Compatibility patch installed, in addition I have gotten several applications to work.  Eventually this VBA code will be rewritten in the C# environment, however at the moment I am just trying to get the code to work.

In the following example the code gets down to the

```
Set pPoint = pActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(X, Y)
```

line and errors out with 
[runtime error 13 Type Mismatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264979%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

I believe it is some sort of reference error, however I cannot figure out where it is hanging.

```
Private Sub pixel3x3picker_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long)
'Code to get a 3 x 3 sample average of pixels similar to the sample tool in photoshop
Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument

Dim pActiveView As IActiveView
Set pActiveView = pMxDoc.FocusMap
Dim pPoint As IPoint
Set pPoint = pActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(X, Y)
```

---

I got it figured out, I had to mess with the references in VBA, I turned on the correct one, however I do not know which one was the "correct one".

[VBA References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr4YC.jpg)

Comment: What error do you get in the output window after you build?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure If I have a good answer for your question.  This is being done in the VBA editor embedded into ArcMap, I do not have the ability to build in it.

Comment: Possibly the same as what's going on here... http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20068/error-creating-ipoint-arcgis-10-invalid-use-of-new-keyword-vba?rq=1

Try fully qualifying the point: `Set pPoint = New esriGeometry.Point`

Comment: @Ryan - sorry. I though you were building an addin.